# Bijection in the Yoneda Lemma

Tags: category-theory, yoneda-lemma

To prove the Yoneda Lemma one defines a bijection between $[\mathcal{A}^{op},\mathbf{Set}](\hom(-,A),X)$ and $X(A)$ and shows that this bijection is natural in $A$ and $X$.

In my textbook this bijection is $\alpha\mapsto \alpha_A(\text{id}_A)$ which was my first thought as well. However, there is the question how we could have defined it alternatively.

So my question is: which alternative is meant and how does one get this idea?

Comment: What alternative do you mean? Maybe the formula for its inverse? Or what else?

Comment: I don't understand the question in the textbook. Are you reading Leinster's book? You forgot to take the dual category $\mathcal{A}^{\mathrm{op}}$, by the way.

Comment: Leinster: "Given $\alpha: \hom(-,A)\to X$, define $\tilde\alpha\in X(A)$ by $\tilde\alpha = \alpha_A(1_A)$. (How else could we possibly define it?)" My question is about this "else".

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg "op" is fixed now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Leinster writes: "How else could we possibly define it?"

This is not understood as an exercise to find another definition.

This is understood in the following sense: There is no real other way to define it, right? You have only one choice.

A german translation would be: "Wie sollte man das auch sonst definieren?"

Comment: The following is a language question: Why is it meant like this and not as I've understood it? (I'd like to avoid such embarrassing questions in the future ;))

Comment: Good question. I think the context matters ...

Comment: And I also think that the word "possibly" could be translated here by "überhaupt", which makes the meaning pretty clear.